# How to increment the number of fetches from the data store

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use the following code to fetch data from the datastore:

```
    posts_query = Greeting.query(
    ancestor=session_key(session_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
    posts = posts_query.fetch(100)
```

The number of fetches is quite huge (i.e. 100) for me and so I want to start first  with 10 fetches then increment it by 10 through the click of a button(I call it a load more button).

Comment: Have look at paging using cursors: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors

Comment: @voscausa I was now able to implement the functionality/answer to my question with the help google app engine ndb query cursors section in the documentation link that you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem (see comments in the question) through the hint that I should look at [GAE NDB Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors).